# Friendly URL for my web with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

i have a problem, my site give me this URL: mysite.com/?nav=1&action=inbox and i want to make it friendly, something like this: mysite.com/inbox

How can help me?

---

Hi, thanks everyone who help me, now i have: mysite.com/1/inbox.html and i want: mysite.com/inbox

Comment: Try one of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=friendly+url+htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use a [generator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php) for .htaccess rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called .htaccess and put it in your root folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

This basically says "if the URL is not a file or a directory, go to index.php".

Then your index.php should look like this:

```
<?php
  $q = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);   
  if($q[1]!=""){
    switch($q[1]){
      case "articles":
        include("articles.php");
        break;
      default:
        include("error-404.php");
    }
  }
  else{
    include("home.php");
  }
?>
```

Add a new `case` for each redirect you need. And use `$q[2]` for the second `/.../` and so on.